# AngulaJS UI-router retry promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my angular project. My question is: What's the best practice to retry and handle correctly a promise inside a resolve?

Right now I am simulating a disconnection or timeout, when that happens the promise is rejected(with a 404), which leaves my application in an inconsistent state. I can't find the best way to retry going to that state when the server is back up, right now nothing happens because the promise was already rejected.

PS. from ui-router wiki, not sure if I couldn't find my answer there, this is the closest thing, which I guess that Ed forgot about it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-lazy-load-states

---

UPDATE(4/30 3:02pm):
While creating the [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RyWvPZneLOjZtB3TXOdK), i realized that the problem is that I'm using a service to return the promise object, then that's why the promise stays as rejected.

Comment: Can you post some boiled down code with your question?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE(5/01 11:30AM)

SOLUTION

After playing with the plunkr last night I realized that I need to check the state of the promise, so I found this which is not too useful. By the way, I am using a service because I only need to resolve that promise once, is just retrieving a catalog from the server side that won't change for the rest of the session. So, just if you are curious, my solution will involve some kind of factory of promises(http gets), so if the promise of the service hasn't been resolved I can create a new one and go to the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the direct answer is, you don't. Promises are only resolved or rejected once, and a failed resolve fails the transition. If you want to recover the transition itself, intercept `$stateChangeError` (or use the error callback of the transition), examine the promise rejection, and attempt to recover and re-initiate the transition. You may want to add some fail-safe code to ensure you don't do this repeatedly.